# Capture isolated parts of a polygon after difference operation in single polygons

Tags: qgis, multi-polygon

In QGIS, I have two layers, each consisting of only one feature.

[image]

After subtracting the grey layer from the orange layer, the resulting layer has also only one feature. I want to access all the resulting polygons separately, that are not connected to each other (like the GeoPandas explode function). Currently, the attribute table of the resulting layer contains only one feature.

[image]

How can I do that? I tried the "promote to multi" function of the geoprocessing tools but the result is still only a single feature.

Comment: How did you determine that it didn't work?  Did it report an error?  How many features are in the corresponding attribute table? Please [Edit] the Question with clarifications.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Since it already is multiploygon, you probably want multipart-to-singlepart, not "promote to multi".

Comment: The terms multipart and singlepart perhaps appear a little unintuitive at first. Multipart is a (polygon) feature consisting of multiple parts (what you have to start with), single part consists of a separate polygon feature for each part. Hence, Vince's suggestion will produce what you are aiming for.

Comment: Indeed, that confused me but it is clear now. Thank you for your help!